# Creating xml dynamically with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I havent used lxml to create xml, so i am somewhat lost. I can make a function, that creates an elemnt:

```
from lxml import etree as ET    
from lxml.builder import E

In [17]: def func():
    ...:     return E("p", "text", key="value")

In [18]: page = (
    ...:     E.xml(
    ...:         E.head(
    ...:             E.title("This is a sample document")
    ...:         ),
    ...:         E.body(
    ...:             func()
    ...:             
    ...:         )
    ...:     )
    ...: )

In [19]: print ET.tostring(page,pretty_print=True)
<xml>
  <head>
    <title>This is a sample document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p key="value">text</p>
  </body>
</xml>
```

How can i make the function to add multiple elements? For example, i would like `func(3)` to create 3 new paragraphs. If the func reurns a list, i get a TypeError.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your function can return multiple elements, then you need to use the [`*` argument syntax](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) to pass these elements as positional arguments to the `E.body()` method:

```
...
    E.body(
        *func()
    )
```

Now `func()` should return a sequence:

```
def func(count):
    result = []
    for i in xrange(count):
        result.append(E("p", "text", key="value"))
    return result
```

Comment: I can't comment to Martijn's answer so I wrote as an answer. def func(count): result = [] for i in xrange(count): result.append(E("p", "text", key="value")) return result Not worked for me, but changing **result = []** into **result = list()** did the trick.